# Оборот с КАК тесно связан со сказуемым?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как, сравнительный-оборот

1. Младенчество прошло, как легкий сон (А. Пушкин). Как легкий сон — обстоятельство.
2. Одни как изумруд, другие как коралл. Оборот с КАК образует именную часть составного сказуемого.
3. Это звучит как ирония. Оборот с КАК тесно связан по смыслу со сказуемым.

**Снег лежал волнами и блестел как сахар** (Л. Толстой).

Вопрос: **как сахар** — это что? Оборот с КАК тесно связан по смыслу со сказуемым?

Answer (score 1):

Запятая ставится. Это обычный сравнительный оборот.

**Снег лежал волнами и блестел, как сахар.** ([Толстой. Русак](http://rvb.ru/tolstoy/01text/vol_10/01text/0169.htm))

Answer (score 1):

Сравнительный оборот в предложении обычно выполняет функцию **обособленного обстоятельства,** но может также являться **необособленным обстоятельством или именной частью сказуемого.**

Младенчество прошло, **как легкий сон** (обособленное обстоятельство).

Лёд блестит **как зеркало** (необособленное обстоятельство, фразеологический оборот).

Одни **как изумруд**, другие **как корал**л (именная часть сказуемого, связка пропущена).

Снег лежал волнами и блестел, **как сахар**.  Запятая поставлена, но она соответствует грамматическому принципу, паузы здесь нет. Такую же позицию занимают необособленные фразеологические обороты (этим объясняются возможные варианты в постановке знаков препинания).